# ServerManager.CommitChanges( ) throws Error: "Cannot write configuration file"

Tags: c#, iis

Here is my code to create an application

```
 public static bool CreateApplication(String websiteName, String applicationName, String AppDIR,String appPoolName)
        {
            try
            {
                var windowsDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot");
                Process.Start(windowsDir+@"\system32\inetsrv\appcmd","unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication");      
                Process.Start(windowsDir+@"\system32\inetsrv\appcmd","unlock config -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication");

                ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();

                if (!applicationName.Contains("/"))
                    applicationName = "/" + applicationName;               

                var app = iisManager.Sites[websiteName].Applications.Add(applicationName, AppDIR);                             
                
                
                app.ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;

                var config = app.GetWebConfiguration();
                var anonsection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", iisManager.Sites[websiteName].Name + applicationName);
                anonsection["enabled"] = false;

                var winsection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", iisManager.Sites[websiteName].Name + applicationName);
                winsection["enabled"] = true;

                iisManager.CommitChanges(); //Blows up here
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Everything is fine until it hit's the commit changes method call.

It throws this error

> Error: Cannot write configuration file

All of the code is verified as working except for where I change the enabled values to false and true.

When I added these in it started to explode.

Is there any way to fix this from code, that can be distributed to other machines?

### Update:

After re-locking the files

like this

```
 Process.Start(windowsDir + @"\system32\inetsrv\appcmd", "lock config -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication");
 Process.Start(windowsDir + @"\system32\inetsrv\appcmd", "lock config -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication");
```

I now get this error

> Error: Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has
> changed on disk

Comment: Why do you use both `appcmd` and `ServerManager`?

Comment: @haim770 does it really make a difference given the error I am experiencing? If so please explain and offer a solution. If not then why does it matter?

Comment: It does matter because both are messing with `applicationHost.config` and both can be used to achieve the same result. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am attempting to create an application programatically, link it to a specific app pool and then change the windows auth to true and anon auth to false

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the second of your two issues (`Error: Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has changed on disk`) for our c# application which we use to configure IIS servers as part of our deploy operation.

For me in the end it was unintentionally nesting two using statements wrapped around the `ServerManager` object that caused the problem.

For your particular situation I would try to add a `using` statement for your reference to `ServerManager` and ensure that the command line `appcmd` calls are outside the using statement or moved within the using statement but translated into API calls via the `ServerManager` object.